# MySQL Workbench run SQL script file Character Set encoding issue

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, character-set

Upon running a .sql file for creating a schema in MySQL Workbench 6.1, it prompts a window saying it cannot decide the right character set

[image]

What's the proper thing to do?

Comment: Always be able to go back to square 1. Take a backup copy of the file (i.e. world_innodb.sql.bak) and carry on. If the system subsequently can't work with that file, then you can retrace your steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is the "world" database downloaded from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html), it is in `latin1` encoding. Use that for importing.

UTF-8 (`utf8` or `utf8mb4` in MySQL) [has become the *de facto* standard nowadays for operating systems and global communications](http://w3techs.com/technologies/history_overview/character_encoding) (except in some countries and specific areas of knowledge), and `utf8` is now the default encoding in MySQL (since 5.5). See also http://utf8everywhere.org

`latin1` was the 1 byte representation of characters for the western languages. MySQL supports several encodings, you can see them by executing:

```
SHOW CHARACTER SET;
```

You asked in a comment:

> Given a `*.sql` file, how do I unambiguously find out its encoding?

If you used `mysqldump` to generate it, it usually presets the encoding used at the beginning [like this](http://pastebin.com/fQhTaJG5) (check the "set names" execution), so that it is imported correctly, without needing to specify it.

In general, it is impossible to know the encoding used of any arbitrary text file, but you can try to auto-detect it with tools like the standard GNU file tool on Amazon Linux `file -i <filename>`. There should be tons of tools like that, even more specialised.

Answer (score -3):

Just close workbench and Restart MYSQL server from local services.
my issue resolved this way...:)

Comment: I know this answer isn't exactly for the question, but it solved the problem I had which could easily be confused with the one given by the poster. Thanks!